# Function to print blank lines Python

Tags: python, function, parameters

I need to create a function named `nine_lines`, this function is going to use another function called `three_lines` to print nine blank lines.

This is what I have, using 3.4

```
  #creating a function within a function
  def new_line():
      print()
  def three_lines():
      new_line()
      new_line()
      new_line()
  def nine_lines():
      three_lines()
      three_lines()
      three_lines()
  nine_lines
```

It prints...

```
  >>>  ================================RESTART================================        
  >>> 
  >>>
```

Comment: You never call your function. Missing `()`

Comment: Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #creating a function within a function
  def new_line():
      print()
  def three_lines():
      new_line()
      new_line()
      new_line()
  def nine_lines():
      three_lines()
      three_lines()
      three_lines()
  nine_lines()
```

I think you were missing the '()' after the nine_lines to call back the function.

An alternative way to print 9 lines is using a loop:

```
for i in range(9):
    print()
```